# Swift 4: В какой последовательности лучше создавать и соединять контроллеры?

Tags: controller, tab, swift4

В приложении планируется порядка 6-8 контроллеров, Table View Controller and View Controller. Они будут соединяться через Navigation Controller и в конце будет один общий Tab Bar Controller.

Вопрос такой - в какой последовательности их лучше создавать и соединять? Пока вижу примерно следующие варианты:

1. Создаются табличные и обычные контроллеры, которые по ходу соединяются между собой навигационными, и тоже по ходу, поочередно, подсоединяются к таб бар контроллеру.
2. Создаются табличные и обычные контроллеры, соединяются между собой навигационными, и в конце, все вместе выделяются и одним разом подсоединяются к таб бар контроллеру.
3. Создается вначале таб бар контроллер, и затем к нему поочередно, по ходу дела, создаются и подключаются остальные контроллеры.

Почему спрашиваю, заметил, что когда, например, создаешь вначале таб бар контроллер, он автоматом создает сразу еще два вью контроллера. И там уже некоторые связи прописаны. А если наоборот, вначале делаешь табл вью или обычные контроллеры и потом подсоединяешь их к таб бар контроллеру, то некоторые из стандартных связей надо прописывать самому. А учитывая то, что всего набирается более 10 разных контроллеров, то хотелось бы как-то и время сэкономить и уменьшить вероятность ошибок.

Какой здесь может быть оптимальный путь и какие могут быть подводные камни?

---

так что, этот вопрос не важен или никто с этим не сталкивался?